# How to downgrade to cuda 10.0 in arch linux?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, cuda, archlinux

I want to downgrade my cuda 10.1 to cuda 10.0 in arch linux as tensorflow requires cuda 10.0 only.

I installed tensorflow on CUDA 10.1 in arch Linux but I didn't know tensorflow-gpu needs CUDA 10.0 or lesser.

I tried tried symlinking the required 10.0 libraries with new 10.1 libraries but it didn't work.

Whenever I try to import tensorflow in python console error shows up that 'libcublas.so.10.0' not found.

So I found out that I can only run tensorflow on CUDA 10.0 so now I want to downgrade my CUDA. But I have no Idea how to do that in arch Linux.

Every time I run `import tensorflow` it gives this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/techievin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/techievin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/techievin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /usr/lib/libcublas.so.10.0: version `libcublas.so.10.0' not found (required by /home/techievin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/techievin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/techievin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/techievin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/techievin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/techievin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/techievin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /usr/lib/libcublas.so.10.0: version `libcublas.so.10.0' not found (required by /home/techievin/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

`pacman -S cuda=="10.0"` is not working.

I searched everywhere but couldn't find any proper answer for arch Linux to downgrade to CUDA 10.0

Comment: There is no need for this at all, ArchLinux has TensorFlow packages in the official repos which are already compiled with Arch's CUDA version, see: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=tensorflow&maintainer=&flagged=

Comment: That is the same error, did you actually remove tensorflow from pip and install it with pacman?

Comment: Now it is giving this error
`ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
`
And Cuda is installed in /opt/cuda and if i try `nvcc --version` It says command not found

Comment: You are not answering my direct question, that means I cannot help you.

Comment: I am sorry, I had not refreshed the feed and I commented. Yes I removed tensorflow from pip and I installed `python-tensorflow-gpu` so now it works completely fine. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Download cuda 10.0 package from here: http://archlinux.arkena.net/archive/packages/c/cuda/cuda-10.0.130-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
2. Install package `sudo pacman -U cuda-10.0.130-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`

Answer (score 6):

I've solved this issue by using [**`yay`**](https://github.com/Jguer/yay). With `yay` you can install older versions of `cuda` and `cudnn`. In my experience this is faster than downloading from [archive.org](https://archive.org/download/archlinux_pkg_cuda).

Install `yay` on Arch:

```
pacman -S --needed git base-devel
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/yay.git
cd yay
makepkg -si
```

Search for the version you need:

```
yay -Ss cuda
yay -Ss cudnn
```

At the moment of writing this answer I needed to downgrade from `cuda` 11.2 to 11.0. So I installed specific versions:

```
pacman -R cuda cudnn
yay -S cuda-11.0 cudnn8-cuda11.0
```

For me, Tensorflow worked smoothly after downgrading.

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing the same issue and have to re-apply the method I used when I was using my old gtx670:

1. [Downgrade the cuda package](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Downgrading_packages)
2. [Prevent it from being upgraded](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Skip_package_from_being_upgraded)

keep in mind that specific Cuda versions need specific nvidia drivers.

Just have a look at the [compatibility matrix](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#binary-compatibility) and eventually prevent also the drivers from upgrading.

Comment: Ok, turns out that arch linux doesn't have cuda 10.0 in their archive nor on aur. They keep them here : https://archive.org/download/archlinux_pkg_cuda/ but it's painfully slow to download, moreover I worry that also downgrading the nvidia drivers could make some trouble. Building is not an option in my case, since the great number of open issues asking for help building tf2.0 and cuda 10.1.
It's very strange that nobody is dealing with this problem, I need to run tf2.0 in a docker environment on my arch machine. Everything used to work well, like 2 years ago..

Comment: I needed 10.0 for Tensorflow as well. Much faster download link here: http://archlinux.arkena.net/archive/packages/c/cuda/

Comment: Update: For some reason I hadn't to downgrade since it seems everything is working well from scratch with Cuda 10.1 and Tensorflow 2.0a, differently from my other Ubuntu machine. Maybe it's due to the Turing architecture having different requirements wrt Volta?